# Disable TTS from Microsoft Agents (Windows 7)

Tags: c#, microsoft-agent

So, I'm making a c# application which also uses the somewhat defunct Microsoft Agents.
I have installed the hotfix for Windows 7 and also tried with Double Agent instead,
It seems like they work average, but the hotfix does most things better than DA, but what both unallows me to, is turn off the TTS.

I does not want my Microsoft Agents to speak with TTS, only by balloon box.

I have tried deactivating on Double Agent configurations, but it crashes the application
showing an error saying that TTS is disabled everytime I use the Speak command, I also tried with the 
Microsoft Agent hotfix, but I didn't found any options to disable TTS, neither can change what TTS mode is to use (in hopes I could turn it off).

How can I turn off the TTS from Microsoft Agents so it only shows the text balloon only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, based on all that time without answer... 
Look's like it's impossible now...

Maybe I should try making my own engine?

Comment: TTS is required to drive balloon output in `Speak()`. If MSAgent cannot find an exact matching TTS engine for the character's `LanguageID` and `TTSModeID` settings, it will find the closest matching TTS engine. If no engine is found, TTS will not work, and chances are neither will the `Speak()` balloon, either. Rather than create your own TTS engine, you should consider just creating your own balloon window instead, and not rely on the character's built-in balloon at all (you can disable the character's balloon). Or, consider using the character's `Think()` method instead of `Speak()`.